# Child element does not stay contained inside parent header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass

## Objective

- Keep the `header__info` contained within in the parent, even if the orientation of the page changes or if scale of the browser window changes

## Problem

I have a parent header and over top of it I have a child div `.header__info`, which contains info about the project: year, title, description and a couple of buttons. **When you scale the page up to 125% in the browser, for example, `header__info` does not stay within the parent `header`.**

I've tried fixing the height of the header by switch out the use of `height: 100vh` and then making the height of `html`, `body` and the parent `header` 100%, but that has not worked either.

```css
/*----------------------------------
VARIABLES
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
FUNCTIONS
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
MIXINS
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
PLACEHOLDERS
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
TYPOGRAPHY
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
FONTS & WEIGHTS
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
COLORS
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
SHADES OF GREY
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
BASE
----------------------------------*/
html {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* 10px browser default */ }

body {
  margin: 0; }

h1 {
  font-size: 18rem;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.4; }

h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

h3 {
  font-size: 2rem; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }

/* Large devices */
/* Large devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-top: 30px; } }

/* Small devices */
/*----------------------------------
GRID
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
BOX SIZING
----------------------------------*/
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/*----------------------------------
CLEARFIX
----------------------------------*/
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0; }

* html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1; }

/* IE6 */
*:first-child + html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1; }

/* IE7 */
.is-bold {
  font-weight: 700; }

.is-grey {
  color: #aaa; }

.is-strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #c62828; }

.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0; }

/* Large devices */
/* Large devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .is-hidden {
    display: none; } }

/* Small devices */
/* Small devices */
/*----------------------------------
HEADER
----------------------------------*/
header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("/src/img/snowglobe1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative; }

.header__info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }

.header__credit {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-right: 45px; }

.header__year {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #c62828; }

.header__intro {
  color: #fff; }

.header__description {
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.header__buttons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 45px; }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .header__info {
    width: 60%; } }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .header__info {
    width: 75%; } }

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .header__info {
    width: 80%; } }

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header__intro {
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 45px; } }

/* Custom query */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .header__buttons {
    margin-left: 25px; } }

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .header__intro {
    font-size: 14rem; }
  .header__description {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    width: 90%; }
  .header__credit {
    display: none; } }

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .header__buttons {
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 3%; }
  .header__description {
    width: 100%; } }

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .header__buttons {
    position: relative;
    left: -2%; } }

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 340px) {
  .header__buttons {
    position: relative;
    left: -4%; } }

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .header__buttons {
    position: relative;
    left: -6%; } }

/*----------------------------------
FOOTER
----------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------
SIDEBAR
----------------------------------*/
.sidebar__title {
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block; }

.sidebar__note {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px; }

.sidebar__byline,
.sidebar__caveat {
  font-size: 1.4rem; }

.sidebar__editor,
.sidebar__byline {
  display: none; }

aside {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 20vw;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding-left: 45px; }

.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-top: 45px; }

/* Large devices */
/* Large devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  aside {
    display: none; } }

/* Small devices */
/* Small devices */
.destination__group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px; }

.destination {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 25vw;
  margin-right: 30px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer; }

.destination--ad {
  cursor: default; }

.destination--kimmswick {
  background-image: url("/src/img/kimmswick.jpg"); }

.destination--stcharles {
  background-image: url("/src/img/st-charles.jpg"); }

.destination--chesterfield {
  background-image: url("/src/img/chesterfield.jpg"); }

.destination--centralwestend {
  background-image: url("/src/img/centralwestend.jpg"); }

.destination--clayton {
  background-image: url("/src/img/clayton.jpg"); }

.destination--cherokee {
  background-image: url("/src/img/cherokee.jpg"); }

.destination--downtown {
  background-image: url("/src/img/downtown.jpg"); }

.destination--maplewood {
  background-image: url("/src/img/maplewood.jpg"); }

.destination--edwardsville {
  background-image: url("/src/img/edwardsville.jpg"); }

.destination--webster {
  background-image: url("/src/img/webster.jpg"); }

.destination--delmarloop {
  background-image: url("/src/img/delmarloop.jpg"); }

.destinations__header {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  margin-bottom: 30px; }

.destination__info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 30px; }

.destination__overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.destination__tease {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff; }

.tease--explainer {
  background: #c62828;
  color: #fff;
  border: none; }
  .tease--explainer p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-transform: none; }

.destination__name {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff; }

.destination__tease,
.destination__name {
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative; }

.destination__buy--item,
.destination__todo--item {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8; }
  .destination__buy--item a,
  .destination__todo--item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999; }
    .destination__buy--item a:hover,
    .destination__todo--item a:hover {
      color: #212121;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #212121; }
  .destination__buy--item span,
  .destination__todo--item span {
    color: #c62828; }

.destination__visit,
.destination__things {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #212121;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212121; }

.destination--activities {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.destination__teaser {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #212121;
  margin-bottom: 30px; }

.destination__title {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 0; }

.destination__thing--title {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #c62828; }

.destination__thing {
  margin-bottom: 45px; }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .destination--activities {
    width: 60vw; }
  .destination {
    width: 28vw;
    margin-right: 15px; } }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .destination {
    width: 46vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px; } }

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .destination--activities {
    width: 70vw; } }

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .destination {
    width: 90vw;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0; } }

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .destination--activities {
    width: 85vw; }
  .destination__buy--item,
  .destination__todo--item {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    width: 95%; }
  .destination__title {
    font-size: 4rem; }
  .destination {
    width: 85vw; } }

/* Small devices */
/*----------------------------------
ADVERTISEMENT
----------------------------------*/
.advertising {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative; }

.advertising--horizontal {
  height: 100px; }

.advertising--square {
  border: none;
  background: none; }

.square {
  background: #ddd;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px; }

.square--center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .advertising--square {
    width: 70%; } }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .advertising--square {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; } }

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .square {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px; } }

/* Medium devices */
/* Small devices */
/* Small devices */
/*----------------------------------
BUTTONS
----------------------------------*/
.button__group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red; }

.button__controls {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px; }

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background: #fff; }

.btn--previous,
.btn--next,
.btn--buy,
.btn--all,
.btn--recommend,
.btn--option {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 700; }

.btn--previous,
.btn--next {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 30px;
  min-width: 225px;
  text-align: center; }

.btn--all,
.btn--recommend,
.btn--option {
  border: 1px solid #aaa; }

.btn--previous {
  color: #c62828;
  border: 1px solid #c62828; }
  .btn--previous .fa-long-arrow-left {
    color: #c62828; }

.btn--all,
.btn--recommend,
.btn--option {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #212121;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  min-width: 225px;
  min-height: 75px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa; }

.btn--all,
.btn--recommend {
  background: #c62828;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center; }
  .btn--all:hover,
  .btn--recommend:hover {
    background: #900;
    border: none; }

.btn--option {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  min-width: 260px;
  min-height: 75px;
  font-size: 1.6rem; }
  .btn--option.is-selected {
    border: 2px solid #c62828;
    color: #c62828; }
  .btn--option .fa-check {
    color: #c62828;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: -40px;
    top: -1px; }
    .btn--option .fa-check.is-grey {
      color: #e7e7e7; }
    .btn--option .fa-check.is-red {
      color: #c62828; }

.btn--sidebar {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  background: transparent;
  color: #212121;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; }
  .btn--sidebar:hover {
    color: #aaa;
    color: #ccc; }

.btn--next,
.btn--buy {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background: #c62828; }

.btn--buy {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none; }
  .btn--buy:visited {
    text-decoration: none; }

.btn--view {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0; }
  .btn--view:hover {
    color: #212121; }

.btn--next {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #900; }
  .btn--next:hover {
    background: #900;
    transition: 0.2s; }

/* Custom query */
@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  .button__group {
    width: 80%; } }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .button__group {
    width: 90%; } }

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .button__group {
    width: 100%; } }

/* Medium devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .btn--option {
    min-width: 275px; }
  .btn--all,
  .btn--recommend {
    min-width: 275px; } }

/* Small devices */
/* Small devices */
/*----------------------------------
GIFT
----------------------------------*/
.gifts {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  width: 80vw;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 45px; }

.gift {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  width: 375px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px; }

.gift__image {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; }

.gift__name,
.gift__price {
  font-weight: 700; }

.gift__name {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900; }

.gift__price {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 900; }

.gift__description {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #212121; }

.gift__link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212121; }

.gift__share {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa; }

.gift__icons {
  text-align: center; }

.gift__link {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c62828; }
  .gift__link:visited {
    color: #c62828; }

/*----------------------------------
GUIDE
----------------------------------*/
.helper {
  height: 15vh; }
  .helper p {
    font-size: 2rem; }

.option {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #212121;
  font-weight: 700; }

/*----------------------------------
ICONS
----------------------------------*/
i.fa-pinterest-p,
i.fa-amazon,
i.fa-twitter,
i.fa-facebook,
i.fa-check,
i.fa-long-arrow-left,
i.fa-times,
i.fa-map-marker,
i.fa-map,
i.fa-envelope,
i.fa-gift {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #212121; }
  i.fa-pinterest-p:visited, i.fa-pinterest-p:focus, i.fa-pinterest-p:active,
  i.fa-amazon:visited,
  i.fa-amazon:focus,
  i.fa-amazon:active,
  i.fa-twitter:visited,
  i.fa-twitter:focus,
  i.fa-twitter:active,
  i.fa-facebook:visited,
  i.fa-facebook:focus,
  i.fa-facebook:active,
  i.fa-check:visited,
  i.fa-check:focus,
  i.fa-check:active,
  i.fa-long-arrow-left:visited,
  i.fa-long-arrow-left:focus,
  i.fa-long-arrow-left:active,
  i.fa-times:visited,
  i.fa-times:focus,
  i.fa-times:active,
  i.fa-map-marker:visited,
  i.fa-map-marker:focus,
  i.fa-map-marker:active,
  i.fa-map:visited,
  i.fa-map:focus,
  i.fa-map:active,
  i.fa-envelope:visited,
  i.fa-envelope:focus,
  i.fa-envelope:active,
  i.fa-gift:visited,
  i.fa-gift:focus,
  i.fa-gift:active {
    color: #212121; }
  i.fa-pinterest-p:hover,
  i.fa-amazon:hover,
  i.fa-twitter:hover,
  i.fa-facebook:hover,
  i.fa-check:hover,
  i.fa-long-arrow-left:hover,
  i.fa-times:hover,
  i.fa-map-marker:hover,
  i.fa-map:hover,
  i.fa-envelope:hover,
  i.fa-gift:hover {
    color: #c62828; }

i.fa-times,
i.fa-long-arrow-right,
i.fa-arrow-right {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 2rem; }

i.fa-long-arrow-left {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px; }

i.fa-pinterest-p,
i.fa-facebook,
i.fa-twitter {
  margin-right: 30px; }

i.fa.fa-amazon {
  margin-right: 15px; }

i.fa-gift {
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 30px; }
  i.fa-gift:hover {
    color: #212121; }

i.fa-circle {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 8px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  display: none; }

i.fa-check {
  cursor: default; }

/*----------------------------------
LIST
----------------------------------*/
ul {
  padding: 0; }

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center; }

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative; }

.panel__progress {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; }

.panel__circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
  .panel__circle.is-selected {
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    background: #c62828; }
  .panel__circle.is-completed {
    border: 1px solid #c62828; }
    .panel__circle.is-completed .fa-check {
      color: #c62828; }

.panel__text {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem; }

.panel__number {
  position: relative;
  top: -22px; }
  .panel__number.is-hidden {
    display: none; }

.panel__pick {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center; }

.panel__title {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 4rem; }

.panel__instructions {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #aaa;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px; }

/* Large devices */
/* Large devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .panel__circle,
  .panel__text {
    display: none; }
  .panel__title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; } }

/* Small devices */
/* Small devices */
/*----------------------------------
MAP
----------------------------------*/
.map {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px; }

/* Large devices */
/* Large devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Medium devices */
/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .map {
    height: 400px; } }

/* Small devices */
```

```html
<header>
<div class="header__overlay destination__overlay"></div>
    <div class="header__info">
        <h2 class="header__year">2016 Edition</h2>
        <h1 class="header__intro">The List</h1>
        <h3 class="header__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, reiciendis voluptate impedit, dolor tempora ratione debitis repudiandae laborum consectetur aperiam. Ad magnam facere quam optio cumque nihil vero perferendis dolores.</h3>

        <div class="header__buttons">
            <button class="btn btn--all">See all 200+ gifts</button>
            <button class="btn btn--recommend">Get a recommendation</button>
            <!-- <button class="btn btn--recommend">Explore a destination</button> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="header__credit">Photo by tk-name</p>
</header>
```

## index.html

```
<header>
<div class="header__overlay destination__overlay"></div>
    <div class="header__info">
        <h2 class="header__year">2016 Edition</h2>
        <h1 class="header__intro">The List</h1>
        <h3 class="header__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, reiciendis voluptate impedit, dolor tempora ratione debitis repudiandae laborum consectetur aperiam. Ad magnam facere quam optio cumque nihil vero perferendis dolores.</h3>

        <div class="header__buttons">
            <button class="btn btn--all">See all 200+ gifts</button>
            <button class="btn btn--recommend">Get a recommendation</button>
            <!-- <button class="btn btn--recommend">Explore a destination</button> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="header__credit">Photo by tk-name</p>
</header>
```

## header.scss

```
/*----------------------------------
HEADER
----------------------------------*/

header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("/src/img/snowglobe1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}

.header__info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header__credit {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: $color-white;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

.header__year {
    color: $color-white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #c62828;
}

.header__intro {
    color: $color-white;
}

.header__description {
    text-align: center;
    color: $color-grey-dark;
    color: $color-black;
    color: $color-white;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    // width: 70%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header__buttons {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .header__info {
        width: 60%;
    }
}

/* Large devices */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .header__info {
        width: 75%;
    }
}

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .header__info {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .header__intro {
        line-height: 1.1;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 45px;
    }
}

/* Custom query */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .header__buttons {
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
}

/* Medium devices */
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .header__intro {
        font-size: 14rem;
    }

    .header__description {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .header__credit {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .header__buttons {
        margin-left: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: 3%;
    }

    .header__description {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 360px) {
    .header__buttons {
        position: relative;
        left: -2%;
    }
}

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 340px) {
    .header__buttons {
        position: relative;
        left: -4%;
    }
}

/* Small devices */
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .header__buttons {
        position: relative;
        left: -6%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or snippet.

Comment: @AllDani.com There are snippets of the `index.html`, which contains the header and the styling for the elements provided above in the `header.scss`

Comment: I mean this: http://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @AllDani.com Added in the snippet

Comment: I zoomed in and don't see any problem..?

Comment: If you expand to full page on the snippet, you should notice that the `header__info` text is taller than the height of the background, and the buttons are not within the `header`. Is this not the case for you? I'm viewing this on Chrome.

Comment: Rather then the tag or css, Which visual element gets out of place? What piece of text?

Comment: The `.header__info` does not stay within the header element. I presume this is an issue with `position:absolute` to center the text over the header?

Comment: I'm asking what piece of visual html isn't as you want it? Not the html tag, not the css class. What visual text, seen on the front end, isn't behaving as wanted?

Comment: The .header__info is not behaving how I want it to as it's not staying within it's parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the parent container "position:relative" and then give the child "position:absolute" then it will always remain in the container. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the problem when things are scaled up to 125% or 150% for example.

Comment: if you change .header__info  to "top:60%; you can see it at 150%.

Comment: .header__info {
    position: relative;
    width:70%;
    margin:auto;
}

Comment: try that instead!

Comment: can scale it up as high as you like

Comment: I've added my full `header.scss` file as your recommendation unfortunately does not work on small screen widths. Can you post an altered version of my `header.scss` or create a CodePen or JSBin as an example

Comment: what you need to do is create media queries

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Do you mind posting a snippet with all of your recommendations together